# Serversided code for updating?

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have a website that when you fill in information and push on a submit button, button1_click() inserts data into the database. I have another button that generates an id that gets the date and '0001' after it and fills it into the textbox. How do I use serverside code to have my functions check to see if it has the 0001 in the database, and if it's in the database make it put in '0002' instead? I know I need to use parameters but I'm confused about how that works and the code used to update the database.. here is my code

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into John_IEP_Crossing_Dock_Shipment values('" + generateidtxt.Text + "','" + hawbtxt.Text + "','" + invrefpotxt.Text + "','" + hppartnumtxt.Text + "','" + iecpartnumtxt.Text + "','" + qtytxt.Text + "','" + bulkstxt.Text + "','" + boxplttxt.Text + "','" + rcvddatetxt.Text + "','" + statustxt.Text + "','" + carriertxt.Text + "','" + shippertxt.Text + "', '', '','','','','',GETDATE(),GETDATE())", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        generateidtxt.Text = "";
        hawbtxt.Text = "";
        invrefpotxt.Text = "";
        hppartnumtxt.Text = "";
        iecpartnumtxt.Text = "";
        qtytxt.Text = "";
        bulkstxt.Text = "";
        boxplttxt.Text = "";
        rcvddatetxt.Text = "";
        statustxt.Text = "";
        carriertxt.Text = "";
        shippertxt.Text = "";
        con.Dispose();

    }

    protected void generateid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        generateidtxt.Text = "from DB";
    }
}
```

here is the sql commands I think I need to use..

```
 insert John_IEP_Crossing_Dock_Shipment (ID)
  select ID = Left(max(ID),10) + '-' + RIGHT('000' + convert(varchar,convert(int,right(max(ID),4)) + 1), 4)
  from John_IEP_Crossing_Dock_Shipment 
  where Left(ID,10) = convert(varchar(10), Getdate(),20)

  select ID = Left(max(ID),10) + '-' + RIGHT('000' + convert(varchar,convert(int,right(max(ID),4)) + 1), 4)
  from John_IEP_Crossing_Dock_Shipment 
  where Left(ID,10) = convert(varchar(10), Getdate(),20)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're asking correctly, do you mean you want to get a value from the newly inserted record and check its value?

If so, you can use @@IDENTITY which will give you the id of the last record inserted into the database from which you can run a SELECT statement and retrieve the data you need for applying your check.

Please refer to the following link for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx

Comment: I have to do something like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx and also this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar.aspx but I don't really understand these examples